# Ensuring MongoDB data base directory has the right read/write permission

Tags: database, mongodb, command-line, backend

After I downloaded MongoDB with Home Brew, I created my “db” directory (using the comman `sudo mkdir -p /data/db` in my terminal). However, I simply can't seem to specify my user permissions (read/write) to the directory. When I try `sudo chown -R [username]:[username] /data/db` I simply get `chown: tobiasrasmussen: illegal group name`, and when I try `sudo chown -R` id -un `/data/db` I get `chown: /data/db: No such file or directory`.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Note: I've browsed through several MongoDB/data/db-related topics on here, but I couldn't seem to find any answers that were directly applicable for my particular issue (or maybe I'm too big a newb).

Comment: Are you sure you are in group `tobiasrasmussen`? Verify with command `groups`

Comment: Yes, I've checked my user with `whoami` and my groups with `groups`.

Comment: Strange, it looks like a simple typo in bash